# setting column width in tabular* with the calc package

Tags: calc

I have a problem setting the column with using the `calc` package, which should be quite straightforward, but I cannot figure it out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{|p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|} 
         \hline
         text 1 & text 2 \\
         \hline
      \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
   
\end{document}
```

This produces a desired output.

[image]

However, if I want to add an additional multiplier, say replace `0.5\linewidth` with `0.9*0.5\linewidth`, I get an error `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).`

After reading the [calc package documentation](https://mirrors.nxthost.com/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/calc.pdf) I saw that there is some requirements with multiplication regarding `dimexpr`, however I cannot figure out what the correct syntax needs to be in order to add this extra multiplication factor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be you could try: `0.9\dimexpr0.5\linewidth\relax` Add the `\relax` wherever you want to finish the `\dimexpr` command

Comment: The first thingy has to be a valid length, and the `*` and `/` operators are pretty restricted, they can only use integers, so `\dimexpr0.5\linewidth*2\relax` would be possible (that's what the `calc` package is inserting, a `\dimexpr`, such that calculations are possible). If you need a factor that is not an integer, the way suggested by @koleygr is the correct approach.

Comment: not directly related to your question but you son't need to load `tabularx` here.

Comment: @Skillmon `\dimexpr` syntax works, but then you don't need the `calc` package.

Comment: @koleygr Thank you very much, it worked. Would have never guessed it on my own.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the syntax of the `calc` package's expressions is the same as `\dimexpr`, iirc, so there is no big difference between why `0.9*0.5\linewidth` and `\dimexpr0.9*0.5\linewidth` fails, both have to start with a valid value of the used type.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle For some reason I cannot compile if I don't load the `tabularx` package. Maybe the `tabcolsep` is in it? Not sure if loading another package would be more appropriate, like `array` or another one...

Comment: @jopeto `array` package is needed for the column types of `p` or `m` etc... This will solve your problem

Comment: @koleygr  m but not p as used here

Comment: @Skillmon the syntax is similar but not the same and in particular  doesn't require `\dimexpr` (`calc` predates etex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm too young... :)

Comment: @koleygr Thank you for the explanation! I changed `tabularx` to `array` in the mwe above as suggested.